# Download of image file is not working

Tags: javascript, java, html, angularjs, image-file

```
$scope.displayTaskOutput = function() {
        console.log("Selected jobId is...."+$scope.widgetForm.query_config.selectedTasks.jobId)
        console.log("Selected File is....."+$scope.widgetForm.query_config.selectedFiles)

        $http({
                url: baseUrl+"/"+$scope.widgetForm.query_config.selectedTasks.jobId+"/download",
                method: "GET",
                params: {fileName:$scope.widgetForm.query_config.selectedFiles},
                headers: {
                    'x-api-key': apiKey,
                    'Content-Type': 'application/json'
                },
                data: ''

            }).success(function(data, status) {
                //console.log(data);
                $scope.taskOutputData = data
                var mimeType = 'image/pjpeg';



                var link = document.createElement('a');


            link.setAttribute('download', $scope.widgetForm.query_config.selectedFiles);
            link.setAttribute('href', 'data:' + mimeType + ';charset=utf-8,' + encodeURIComponent(data));
            link.click();
            }).error(function(data, status) {
                console.log("failed:" + status);
                console.log("data : " + data.message);

            });
    };
```

Here when I am trying to download a text file it is getting downloadded and openning fine but othere than text file when I am trying to download a jpg,pdf,png file it is getting downloaded but getting corrupted when I am trying to open it it doesnot open and says "File cannot be opened since it contains errors"

Comment: try setting the content type to "image/jpg" or have a look at this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31690293/angular-http-get-download-file-from-spring-mvc-server

Comment: tried the samething but still same...issue not resolved...pls help

Comment: do I need to set anything in the serverside