# Download file from server with angular

Tags: javascript, java, angularjs, spring, model-view-controller

I want to download file from the server by REST. I want to pass some params to my program in JAVA. I found FileSaver.js library which works nice but not in Safari 8. How can I download file in Safari? Something like this [angular http get](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31690293/angular-http-get-download-file-from-spring-mvc-server) works only in Google Chrome and I don't know how to pass a param to http get. I use JAVA with Spring MVC

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On the backend side we serve the file like this:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/fileService/temp/{temporalLink}", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public ResponseEntity<byte[]> getFileByTemporalLink(@PathVariable @NotNull String temporalLink) {

    byte[] fileContent; // get the file content somehow
    String fileName; // and file name
    String mediaType; // and media type

    HttpHeaders headers = new HttpHeaders();
    headers.setContentType(MediaType.parseMediaType(mediaType));
    headers.setContentDispositionFormData("attachment", fileName);
    return new ResponseEntity<>(fileContent, headers, HttpStatus.OK);
}
```

and on the front-end we ask for it like this:

And inside controller:

```
 $scope.exportProductToPdf = function (someParams) {    
        getFileDownloadLink(someParams).then(function (response) {
                $window.location.href = '/fileService/temp/' + response;
            });
        };
```

// somewhere in the code

```
var getFileDownloadLink = function(someParams) { 

     //we do some promise work here to determine what file is being asked
     // but basically we resolve the filename. 

    return $q(function(resolve, reject) {
        //some work here...
        resolve("filename.png");

    });
```

}

Comment: How fileDownloadLink function looks like?